# How to join Dataframe with one-column dataset without using column names in dataset

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, join, dataset

Let's consider:

```
val columnNames: Seq[String] = Seq[String]("col_1") // column present in DataFrame df
df.join(usingColumns = columnNames, right = ds)) // ds is some dataset that has exactly one column.
// the problem is about the fact that I don't know name of this column? I only know that 
// df.col("col_1") and ds.col(???)` has the same types.
```

Is it possible to do this join?

Answer (score 1):

you can use something like :

package utils

```
object Extensions {
    implicit class DataFrameExtensions(df: DataFrame) {
        def selecti(indices: Int*) = {
            val cols = df.columns
            df.select(indices.map(cols(_)):_*)
        }
    }
}
```

then use this to select column by numbers :

```
import utils.Extensions._

df.selecti(1,2,3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the "col_1" from the first dataframe will always join to the single column in the ds dataframe you can just rename the column in the ds data frame with a single column like below. Then your join using names only need reference "col_1"

```scala
// set the name of the column in ds to col_1
val ds2 = ds.toDF("col_1")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the column name of the dataset to `col_1`:

```
val result = df.join(ds.withColumnRenamed(ds.columns(0), "col_1"), "col_1", "right")
```